# Flutter how to download a pdf file and store it in my phone

Tags: flutter, dart

hello i want to download a pdf file from a link in my flutter application itryed a lot of methode exemple and package without  any result to said `dio` `flutter_downloader` in every time i do not found any thing in my storage i'm asking if there is a dowumentation or an exmple

```
Future <void> dow5tn()async{

    var dir=await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Dio dio=Dio();
    dio.download('http://192.168.43.24:27017/api/posts/uknoww','${dir.path}/filename.pdf');
  }
```

i tryed this code with a lot others without any thing
i need some helps and thank you

Comment: 1. Have you checked Dio documentation? [check it here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

2. Have you tried to retrieve this response? 
*response = await dio.download("https://www.google.com/", "./xx.html");*
3. Can you please paste what is the error?

Comment: no error the download completeted successfullly but i do not find any files

Comment: Then please debug and check(maybe publish here the method `getApplicationDocumentDirectory();` ) the content in `var dir` and what does `${dir.path}`   should return.

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'Directory: '' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30) the same probleme and i got this error

Comment: have an exemple wich work to post itù

Comment: Ok, that's permission. Please, check the answer I published below.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly connected to authorization/permission.

Alternatives:

> 1. Use [Flutter Downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader#-example-tab-) like this example below:

```
final downlodFileTask = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'set the URL link to your file',
  savedDir: 'here you will set the path to directory',
  showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar
  openFileFromNotification: true,
);
```

> 2. Add permission to your Android Manifest and info.plist (ios) like that:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.yyy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
</manifest>
```

Comment: can explain some more or give me an exemple

Comment: Add platform permission in android manifest and infoplist for iOS